# How can i make guild counter in my bot status. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I make my bot shows guild counter in status?
I'm new to Discord.py and I want help with the latest version.

`await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(f'prefix $ | Serving (...) guilds'))`

btw I'm not good at English, sorry if my question will not be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `bot.guilds`, here you have an example on how to update the activity whenever the bot joins/leaves a guild

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    current_guilds = len(bot.guilds)
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(f'prefix $ | Serving {current_guilds} guilds'))


@bot.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    current_guilds = len(bot.guilds)
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(f'prefix $ | Serving {current_guilds} guilds'))
```

Reference:

- [bot.guilds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20guilds#discord.ext.commands.Bot.guilds)
- [on_guild_join](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild_#discord.on_guild_join)
- [on_guild_remove](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild_#discord.on_guild_remove)